# Storing a CollectionProperty in the whole .blend file scope

Tags: python, properties, blend-files, data-blocks

I'm working on an addon where now I am trying to store a `CollectionProperty` (containing custom `PropertyGroup` class elements) in a .blend file globally, as in there is one such property in the .blend file. So far I haven't had issues storing properties on a per-world, per-object or per-scene basis. But what I am trying to achieve is more like a data collection. Something similar to images, meshes, materials etc. How can this be done?

Comment: Long story short it can't be done like that. Here's a recent discussion exploring possible workarounds https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-properties-that-need-to-be-accessed-by-all-scenes/1359734